# Custom Shape - Bottom Navigation Bar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, custom-painter

I am trying to add a custom shape for my Bottom Navigation Bar. I tried ContinuousRectangleBorder and Custom Paint. But noting worked now. Can someone please help me?

[Nav Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlIUZ.png)

```
class BottomBarBorder extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    Size size = rect.size;
    double horizontalOffset = size.height / 2;
    double horizontalRoundingPoint = size.height / 25;

    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 1.4);
    var firstControlPoint = new Offset(horizontalRoundingPoint, 
     size.height);
    var firstEndPoint = new Offset(horizontalOffset, size.height);
    var secondControlPoint =
        new Offset(size.width - horizontalOffset, size.height);
    var thirdControlPoint =
        new Offset(size.width - horizontalOffset, size.height);
    var thirdMiddlePoint =
        new Offset(size.width - horizontalRoundingPoint, size.height);
    var thirdEndPoint = new Offset(size.width, size.height / 1.6);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy);
    path.cubicTo(
        thirdControlPoint.dx,
        thirdControlPoint.dy,
        thirdMiddlePoint.dx,
        thirdMiddlePoint.dy,
        thirdEndPoint.dx,
        thirdEndPoint.dy);

    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height / 3);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you mention all things(code) you have already tried?

Comment: @DarshShah I have added my code.